# Android profiler how to reduce native memory usage

Tags: android, performance, android-profiler

I'm inspecting my app with android studio profiler and try to find some cause of lag and for increase the smoothest of the app. When I'm compare it to exemple found on website they have a really small size for the native part.

If you look at the picture for 270MB I have 185.2MB for the native part

[image]

What is this exactly and where this is come from and how can I reduce it ?